# String to 3 Arrays with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

Hi folks I have a block of text which i want to split in to three parts but i have noticed there is nothing common with these parts that i could use as a delimeter for the explode() function.

```
$description = '£5.97 for a Pillowheads Children’s Backpack worth £11.95 from Intelex Ltd - save 50% on your choice of five adorable designsNeed to know: Save 50% on an Intelex Ltd Pillowheads Children’s Backpack; Choose from five cute and cuddly designs; Postage and packaging is not included and costs £3.95; The perfect stocking filler this Christmas; What & why: Give your little ones an adorably cute, yet totally practical gift this Christmas with a cuddly creature that doubles as a backpack! For just £5.97 choose one of these gorgeous little Pillowheads Children’s Backpacks from Intelex Ltd. With a gorgeous selection of five fluffy animals to choose from, there's sure to be a pack to suit your little pride and joy! Designed with high-quality adjustable back straps and an inner lining for maximum support, these versatile bags will please even the most fussiest of toy lovers! choose one of the following designs: - Cosy Bee - Ladybird - Monkey - Pig - Puppy Each backpack is 43cm x 20xm in size and can be surface cleaned with a damp sponge. about Intelex Ltd Innovators of the muscle-relieving microwaveable herbal heat pack, Intelex Ltd have set the industry standard for quality and safety. Discover an inexpensive, fun and soothing way to relax in comfort at home with a range of products that combine practicality, comfort and style.By the way: Multiple vouchers may be purchased; This product is suitable for children aged three years ; and over; To order, please phone             0871 911 1770      , quoting your unique kgbdeals voucher code, stating which style you would like and provide your delivery details; Please allow 48 hours for your voucher code to be ; activated';
```

is there any way i can split this the 3 blocks are need to know: What and Why and By the way?

EDIT:

```
$description = preg_split('/Need to know:| What & why:|By the way:/i', $product['text']['desc'], 3);
```

Ok got the by the way bit in array but the 'need to know' and 'What &why' bit are sill in same array, can anyone help with this ? :)

Comment: I think you're gonna need to find another way to get the info you want. Not sure where you're getting this data from, but I assume you're scraping it from a site. Usually when there's a description like this, there's a breakdown somewhere else (like a product name and price).

Comment: Which three parts do you mean?

Comment: This data is from an advertisers feed that the website is an affiliate for. The description is the part that needs split the rest is fine :) @Jermaclus, Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_split('/Need to know:|What & why:|By the way:/i', ''£5.97 for a Pillowheads Children?s Backpack worth £11.95 from Intelex Ltd - save 50% on your choice of five adorable designsNeed to know: Save 50% on an Intelex Ltd Pillowheads Children?s Backpack; Choose from five cute and cuddly designs; Postage and packaging is not included and costs £3.95; The perfect stocking filler this Christmas; What & why: Give your little ones an adorably cute, yet totally practical gift this Christmas with a cuddly creature that doubles as a backpack! For just £5.97 choose one of these gorgeous little Pillowheads Children?s Backpacks from Intelex Ltd. With a gorgeous selection of five fluffy animals to choose from, there's sure to be a pack to suit your little pride and joy! Designed with high-quality adjustable back straps and an inner lining for maximum support, these versatile bags will please even the most fussiest of toy lovers! choose one of the following designs: - Cosy Bee - Ladybird - Monkey - Pig - Puppy Each backpack is 43cm x 20xm in size and can be surface cleaned with a damp sponge. about Intelex Ltd Innovators of the muscle-relieving microwaveable herbal heat pack, Intelex Ltd have set the industry standard for quality and safety. Discover an inexpensive, fun and soothing way to relax in comfort at home with a range of products that combine practicality, comfort and style.By the way: Multiple vouchers may be purchased; This product is suitable for children aged three years ; and over; To order, please phone 0871 911 1770 , quoting your unique kgbdeals voucher code, stating which style you would like and provide your delivery details; Please allow 48 hours for your voucher code to be ; activated'', null, 1);
```

Result:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => '£5.97 for a Pillowheads Children?s Backpack worth £11.95 from Intelex Ltd - save 50% on your choice of five adorable designs
    [1] =>  Save 50% on an Intelex Ltd Pillowheads Children?s Backpack; Choose from five cute and cuddly designs; Postage and packaging is not included and costs £3.95; The perfect stocking filler this Christmas; 
    [2] =>  Give your little ones an adorably cute, yet totally practical gift this Christmas with a cuddly creature that doubles as a backpack! For just £5.97 choose one of these gorgeous little Pillowheads Children?s Backpacks from Intelex Ltd. With a gorgeous selection of five fluffy animals to choose from, there's sure to be a pack to suit your little pride and joy! Designed with high-quality adjustable back straps and an inner lining for maximum support, these versatile bags will please even the most fussiest of toy lovers! choose one of the following designs: - Cosy Bee - Ladybird - Monkey - Pig - Puppy Each backpack is 43cm x 20xm in size and can be surface cleaned with a damp sponge. about Intelex Ltd Innovators of the muscle-relieving microwaveable herbal heat pack, Intelex Ltd have set the industry standard for quality and safety. Discover an inexpensive, fun and soothing way to relax in comfort at home with a range of products that combine practicality, comfort and style.
    [3] =>  Multiple vouchers may be purchased; This product is suitable for children aged three years ; and over; To order, please phone 0871 911 1770 , quoting your unique kgbdeals voucher code, stating which style you would like and provide your delivery details; Please allow 48 hours for your voucher code to be ; activated'
)
```

Comment: OHHHHHHHH.  He literally wanted it split on "What & Why" not explain what to split on and why.

Comment: preg_split('/Need to know:/i/What & why:|By the way:/i', $product['text']['desc'], null, 2);

Comment: tried this and getting unknown modifier :S the regex functions hate me lol

Comment: You have to escape the slashes (Two backslashes here, as one is an entity for PHP), as they are used as delimiters.

Comment: hmmm yours gave a great result why am I getting an error is it impossible to add the a fourth section for Need to know?

Comment: nearly got it now lol, I got it in 3 sections but the need to know block and what & why are now together this is what code i got: preg_split('/Need to know:| What & why:|By the way:/i', $product['text']['desc'], null, 2);

Comment: @Michael Robinson I tried the preg_split('/Need to know:|What & why:|By the way:/i' ... but its still joining the need to know and what and why together, :S

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Disregard this.  I misread the post.  Leaving content up because it works for arbitrary strings.

---

Personally, I'd split on the whitespace.  There's probably better places, but not without more specifics as to the application.

Here's a quick an dirty approach (using the [wordwrap](https://www.php.net/wordwrap) function):

```
// Number of desired chunks
$chunks = 3;
$data = "LONG CHUNK OF TEXT HERE";

// Prep the data by removing newlines.
$data = str_replace("\n", '', $data);

// Use the built in wordwrap function to split to size
$data = wordwrap($data, ceil(strlen($data) / $chunks));

// Split on the newly inserted newlines
$parts = explode("\n", $data);

// $parts is now an array with $chunks number of parts, all about the same length.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split it by substring:

```
$description = "£5.97 for a Pillowheads Children’s Backpack worth £11.95 from Intelex Ltd - save 50% on your choice of five adorable designsNeed to know: Save 50% on an Intelex Ltd Pillowheads Children’s Backpack; Choose from five cute and cuddly designs; Postage and packaging is not included and costs £3.95; The perfect stocking filler this Christmas; What & why: Give your little ones an adorably cute, yet totally practical gift this Christmas with a cuddly creature that doubles as a backpack! For just £5.97 choose one of these gorgeous little Pillowheads Children’s Backpacks from Intelex Ltd. With a gorgeous selection of five fluffy animals to choose from, there's sure to be a pack to suit your little pride and joy! Designed with high-quality adjustable back straps and an inner lining for maximum support, these versatile bags will please even the most fussiest of toy lovers! choose one of the following designs: - Cosy Bee - Ladybird - Monkey - Pig - Puppy Each backpack is 43cm x 20xm in size and can be surface cleaned with a damp sponge. about Intelex Ltd Innovators of the muscle-relieving microwaveable herbal heat pack, Intelex Ltd have set the industry standard for quality and safety. Discover an inexpensive, fun and soothing way to relax in comfort at home with a range of products that combine practicality, comfort and style.By the way: Multiple vouchers may be purchased; This product is suitable for children aged three years ; and over; To order, please phone             0871 911 1770      , quoting your unique kgbdeals voucher code, stating which style you would like and provide your delivery details; Please allow 48 hours for your voucher code to be ; activated";

$d_length = strlen($description);
$part = (int) ($d_length / 3);

$p1 = substr($description, 0, $part);
$p2 = substr($description, $part, $part);
$p3 = substr($description, ($part*2));

echo $p1.PHP_EOL;
echo $p2.PHP_EOL;
echo $p3.PHP_EOL;
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/QIuklFW7

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as regular expressions but:

```
$start2 = strpos($description, "What & why:");
$start3 = strpos($description, "By the way:"); 
$part1 = substr($description, 0, $start2);
$part2 = substr($description, $start2, $start3 - $start2);
$part3 = substr($description, $start3);
```

Edit: Do this to exclude the What & why/By the way text:

```
$start2 = strpos($description, "What & why:") + strlen("What & why:");
$start3 = strpos($description, "By the way:") + strlen("By the way:");
$end1 = $start2 - strlen("What & why:");
$end2 = $start3 - strlen("By the way:") - $start2;

$part1 = substr($description, 0, $end1);
$part2 = substr($description, $start2, $end2);
$part3 = substr($description, $start3);
```

Comment: hi thanks for your help but the regular expression is a better option for me, Thanks for your time tho :)

Answer (score -1):

If there is a certain lenght each part can contain you can split them up using the php strpos() function. Otherwise you can check on a point and Capital after each part? Hope this helps.